# Slack WebAPI conversations.unarchive fails with not_in_channel

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

My slack app is listening for the channel_archived event so it can check to see if a very important slack channel was archived:

```
app.event('channel_archive', async ({ event, context }) => {  
    if (event.channel === redacted) {
        fns.textOutput(event.user, "Hello <@"+event.user+"> I noticed you archived the redacted channel. This channel is used by thousands of redacted for slack training.\n"+
        "I have un-archived it so no need to worry, just please be more careful about what you are archiving")
        unArchiveChannel()
    } 
});
```

All of this works and it calls the unArchiveChannel() function which can be seen here:

```
async function unArchiveChannel() {
    try {
        const result = await app.client.conversations.unarchive({
        // Bot token
        token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
        // Channel to unarchive
        channel: redacted,
        })
        console.log(result)
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

My bot token has all the right scopes: channels:manage, groups:write, im:write  and mpim:write. And I used `/invite @(my bots username)` to invite it to the channel. However, when I actually archive the channel in question my function is called but it gives me the error not_in_channel and it fails to unarchive the channel. The error is not listed [in the documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.unarchive) so i'm lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reached out to slack's help center and they emailed me back telling me there was an error in their documentation. You cannot use a bot token to authorize the conversations.unarchive method.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Developers that answer their own questions are truly the kings of SO.  This is the only place I could find this information.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Slack and they wrote me to add the user token scope: `channels:write`
So in the OAuth URL add: `&user_scope=channels:write`